# What do device (character special) file sizes mean?

Tags: linux, bash, linux-device-driver

Using ls -l normally results in a long listing that includes the file size...

```
-rw-r--r--@  1 user1  staff   881344 Sep  1 15:35 someFile.png
```

On macOS 10.13.5, and Ubuntu 20.04, character special (device) file sizes are very different...

```
crw-------  1 root           wheel      31,   0 Aug 30 16:11 autofs
```

In this case, what does the "31,   0" mean?

Answer (score 5):

> what does the "31, 0" mean?

It's the major/minor numbers of character device.

See these:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97676/how-to-find-the-driver-module-associated-with-a-device-on-linux

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/linuxonibm/com.ibm.linux.z.lgdd/lgdd_c_udev.html

Answer (score 1):

### Read carefully the documentation of [ls(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) then about [inode(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inode.7.html)

31 is a major device number, 0 is a minor device number.

Remember that [ls(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) would use [stat(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ls.2.html) (you might check using [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html)...), so read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) then [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)

Sometimes, `ls` might be some shell alias or function. So read documentation of [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/). Try also `/bin/ls --help`

On GNU Linux, read documentation of [coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/). And it is [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html), **you could download and study its source code !**

On MacOSX, the [operating system](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/) [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system)) might have different [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call).

Be however aware of [udev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev) (on Linux).

Comment: I'm sure this is all correct, but @artm's answer is more succinct.